# Printing a number, then erasing it and printing another number in its place

Tags: c

I am making a simple roulette game, and I want to implement a roulette spinning code, so like in my terminal I would have something like this Spinning: 25 then the number after spinning will change, so it erases that 25 and then it's Spinning: 14 then Spinning: 35 and eventually it stops. All I can do is make it look like this:

```
Spinning: 24
Spinning: 34
Spinning: 2
Spinning: x...
etc..
```

basically it's just random numbers. I am just curious is this possible to get rid of this Spinning: x spamming and just make it one Spinning: x with x changing constantly in ONE place. If I used `printf("Spinning: %d", rand()%36+1);` then `printf("Spinning: %d, rand()36%+1)` it is just going to stack on each other, but I want my number changes to change only in ONE place if that makes sense.

Comment: Does `'\b'` work?

Comment: Write a CR instead of a NL and then right justify your number in a field that is two characters wide. When it's done, THEN you can write an NL.

Comment: Try `printf("Spinning: %2d\r" ...)`.  That is, use `\r` instead of `\n`

Comment: Thank you, didn't really have any practice with `\b` and `\r` , I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On many, if not most, consoles, the `\r` (carriage return) character will set the cursor to the start of the current line. So, in such cases, adding that character to the *beginning* of your output would work:

```c
printf("\rSpinning: %d    ", rand()%36+1);
```

I have also added a few spaces at the end, just in case the 'new' number is shorter than the 'old'.

---

On the origin of the name, "Carriage Return," Wikipedia has a [good article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

Comment: Oh that would work, thanks. Also, do you know how I would make the number after "Spinning: " be actually visible, that it's changing? Because If I make a loop so it does the  `printf("\rSpinning: %d    ", rand()%36+1);` multiple times, the computer just runs through the loop that fast, that I can just see the final result, can I make some kind of a delay in the loop so the changes are visible for the human eye? So you can actually see numbers changing.

Comment: @Norbertas Most platforms/compilers have some form of the [`sleep()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) function; on Linux, this takes a value in seconds (maybe too slow for you); on Windows, it takes a value in milliseconds (much nicer, IMHO).

Comment: Also `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf`.